# Comparing a string to a directory

Tags: command-line, scripts

I can't understand why these lines won't work:

```bsh
prim=$(lsblk -o MOUNTPOINT -nr /dev/$hdd);

echo $prim;

if [[ "$prim" == "/" ]] 
   then echo "ok";
fi
```

The first `echo` gives `/` as output, so it should enter the `if`, but it won't work. Am I missing something?

`$hdd` is obtained from `read -p "blabla" hdd;`.

I've tried trimming the first line result, but since it's a directory, I can't do nothing.

Maybe looking at the whole script is easier, but the problem seems to be in the part already posted.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
clear
lsblk --scsi
read -p "wich hdd you want to operate with? " hdd

echo "starting operations. . . (wait)"
    #controllo esistenza disco
if [ ! $(lsblk /dev/$hdd) ] 2>/dev/null 
         then echo "select an existing hdd"
else 
    #estrapolo punto mount
    prim=$(lsblk -o MOUNTPOINT -nr /dev/$hdd)   
    echo "$prim"
    #controllo scelta se è disco primario
    if [ "$prim" == "/" ] 
        then echo "error!! $hdd is the primary disk, can't operate on that disk"
    else
        #mostro opzioni
        echo ""
        echo "options : "
        echo ""
        echo "1)format"
        echo "2)info "
        echo "3)show content"
        echo ""
        read -p "choose option : " opt

    
        if [ $opt = 1 ]                 
                    then  echo "1"
        elif [ $opt = 2 ] 
                    #mostro info disco selezionato
                    then echo "2" 
        elif [ $opt = 3 ] 
                    then echo "3"
        else echo "insert a correct option"
        fi
    fi
fi
```

Comment: You have to learn bash syntax. There's no need of `;` at the end of each sentence and if statements are in the form `if ... then... fi`. Check the bash manual and use shellcheck: `sudo apt install shellcheck`, then `shellcheck yourscript`, or the online [https://www.shellcheck.net/](https://www.shellcheck.net/).

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I missed the `then` :(... but always use shellcheck :)

Comment: i'll try deleting the semicolons, otherwise is my terminal beign sassy ahah

Comment: The script works fine for me. The semicolons do not affect it. What do you input as `hdd`? Do you input the whole device, e.g `/dev/sda`, or a partition, e.g. `/dev/sda3`? As the script is built, the input should be as the second case.

Comment: for examble take from the lsblk --scsi command wich device is connected, in my case there are just sda( wich contains the SO) and sdb wich is a usb. if i digit sda in the read it should enter the if where the problem is, but it just bypass that part

Comment: So you want to find if `/` is **included** in `$prim`, in contrast to if `$prim` **is** `/`, and if yes `echo ok`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem depends on the input that's assigned to `$hdd`. If you enter something like `sda1` (with partition number), the script works. But it appears you expect input like `sda` (without partition number). In the latter case, `$prim` contains the names of each partition, separated by a new line, so it will never be an exact match for `/`. You also cannot use `=~` to search for substrings because every partition, except [swap], will include `/`.

You can try splitting `$prim`, and checking each part:

```
quit=0
for part in $prim ; do
    if [[ "$part" == "/" ]] ; then
        quit=1
    fi
done

if [[ $quit == '1' ]] ; then
    echo "error!! $hdd is the primary disk, can't operate on that disk"
else
    # ...
fi
```

Comment: i'll try that asap and flag the answer as solved if it work, thx in advance

Comment: @userone Made some correction to the explanation (referred to `hdd` when meant `prim`).  The code is the same though.